# Contact form sender email

Tags: email, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I've spent huge amount of hours on Google and can't find the solution.

I am using Wordpress and I want to find some plugin or any other solution which can do the following:
When user sends contact form on my website I receive it on my Gmail but sender email is default Wordpress email. I would like if the sender email could be the email address they input in contact form.

So, if johndoe@mail.com sends me an contact form, it would be awesome if I would receive an email from johndoe@mail.com, and not from mywebsite@mail.com.

I hope this can be done in one way or another.

Comment: this concerns the plugin Contact Form 7 then contact the support of this plugin

Comment: It can be impossible in some server configurations to send emails as someone from an external domain, maybe you should rather try the reply-to [header](https://contactform7.com/adding-cc-bcc-and-other-mail-headers/).

Answer (score 2):

Sending an email from an address you don't own will mean you run into problems with countermeasures again email spoofing (e.g SPF), as you're effectively impersonating the user's email address to send your email.

You could put the user email address as the name, but send the email from an address you own

For contact form 7 an example would be to put in the "from" field:

```
[email] <wordpress@yourdomain.com>
```

Or if you also want their name to show you could do something like:

```
[name] ([email]) <wordpress@yourdomain.ccom
```

The emails will still come from wordpress@yourdomain.com but you'll have the information in the from field in your mail client or system, which may be enough depending on what you're trying to achieve.